# undefined reference error when I pass reference of structure

Tags: c++, reference, structure

I don't know why I get this error when I try to run this code ... What is the problem with this when I pass the reference of my structure...

This is the error :

```
undefined reference to citire(type)
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct type {
    int x[500] = {0};
    int y[500] = {0};
    int lx = 0;
    int ly = 0;
    int aparitii[10000] = {0};
};

void citire(type s);
bool estePrim(type s);
int sumaCfr(type s);
void createY(type s);
void printY(type s);

int main()
{
    type s;

    citire(s);
    cout<<"X LENGTH = "<<s.lx<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void citire(type &s)
{
    int i = -1;
    cin>>s.x[++i];
    while (s.x[i] != 0) {
        cout<<"Insert " << i + 1<< " value"<<endl;
        cin>>s.x[++i];
    }
    s.lx = i;
}
```

Comment: Your prototype does not match your definition: `void citire(type s)` versus `void citire(type &s)`. Your compiler should have warned you about this - did you forget to enable warnings, or did you just ignore them ?

Comment: @PaulR the compiler shouldn't warn, C++ has overloaded functions. The programmer intent might have been to call `citire(type)` defined in another unit

Comment: @M.M: [gcc will warn about the missing prototype if you have `-Wmissing-declarations`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b8573173e9c477d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the parameter type of function declaration and definition don't match. `type` (i.e. pass by value) and `type&` (i.e. pass by reference) are not the same thing.

You need to make them consistent, if you want to pass it by reference, then change the declaration to:

```
void citire(type& s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function declaration should correspond to your implementation

```
...
void citire(type& s);
...
int main()
{
...
}

void citire(type& s)
{
    int i = -1;
    cin>>s.x[++i];
    while (s.x[i] != 0) {
        cout<<"Insert " << i + 1<< " value"<<endl;
        cin>>s.x[++i];
    }
    s.lx = i;
}
```